# How to find database file version?

Tags: sqlite, version

I have a few SQLite database files. I want to know the database file version (if the database was created with sqlite2 or sqlite3 or any other main/sub version) not the SQLite library or driver or user_version or schema_version.

Answer (score 178):

You can write this command in any sqlite explorer which will give the sqlite version

```
select sqlite_version();
```

Comment: This will return the library version, not the database file version.

Comment: @laalto comment confirmed by this official doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#sqlite_version

Comment: Indeed, the preceding function in @Paolo link refer to sqlite_source_id(), with that you just has to see SQLite release date and you can get the version

Answer (score 107):

You can get version number of a database file by the [`Magic Header String`](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html#magic_header_string):

- sqlite2 ==> first 48 bytes
- sqlite3 ==> first 16 bytes

---

```
$ head -c 48 file2.db
** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **

$ head -c 16 file3.db
SQLite format 3
```

---

The easier way is using the `file` command:

```
$ file file2.db
file2.db: SQLite 2.x database

$ file file3.db
file3.db: SQLite 3.x database
```

Comment: The naive way is to open the file with Notepad++ (don't do this if the file is big!)

Comment: @PaoloFulgoni [XVI32](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm) is also a nice tool for these tasks.

Answer (score 39):

#### Get `user_version`

Run SQL: `PRAGMA user_version;`

#### Get `schema_version`:

Run SQL: `PRAGMA schema_version;`

When create database file (`.db`), `user_version` can be set by user.

Comment: **pragma schema_version** is what was asked for.

Answer (score 24):

The correct answer from version 3 of sqlite program is:

```
sqlite3 --version
```

Comment: This is the version of the sqlite3 program, not the version of the database created by SQLite.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract the information from the [file header](http://sqlite.org/fileformat.html). It will require you to open the database file 'by hand' but I don't know if there is an API function to get this information.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open the python shell then write these steps:

```
import sqlite3

sqlite3.sqlite_version
```

Comment: This gives you the sqlite3 version used by Python.

Comment: May not be correct for some users, but I should point out that in my case, using Django on Ubuntu 18.04, it actually was the only way that worked.  Trying "sqlite3 --version" at the command shell, oddly, would claim that sqlite3 was not installed, whereas doing it inside python told me what version django/python was using, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')

data = cursor.fetchone()
print(f"SQLite version: {data[0]}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Check manual file

sqlite3.version
The version number of this module, as a string. This is not the version of the SQLite library.

sqlite3.version_info
The version number of this module, as a tuple of integers. This is not the version of the SQLite library.

sqlite3.sqlite_version
The version number of the run-time SQLite library, as a string.

sqlite3.sqlite_version_info
The version number of the run-time SQLite library, as a tuple of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the easiest method to determine the version of sqlite.
Run the Python IDLE Shell, then do the following:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

In my case it was 2.6.0.
Hope this helps...
Mark

Comment: fyi, to run the Python IDLE Shell, simply type in `python` in the terminal, you'll then see `>>>`

Comment: This gives the version of the module, not the SQLite version. To do so, use `sqlite3.sqlite_version`. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt, if you type `sqlite3` and hit enter, it will automatically give the version number at the very first.

`sqlite3`

[image]

Comment: Read careful: even if answered a lot, this was not asked for.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a data connection to it in Visual Studio, you can right click on the data base in Server Explorer, select properties, and the version will be shown in the properties window, (under Version, surprisingly).  You might need to left click the database first to open it.

Comment: I think OP is asking about sqlite not sql-server.