# How do i know which drivers version of SQLITE is available on my system?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am using `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` it gives me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite )
```

But i want to know that what version of SQLITE is installed on my systems?

Comment: please see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646353/how-to-find-sqlite-database-file-version

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary please add this as an answer.