# sqlite timestamp is not working

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to build an sqlite db, and having timestamp as one of the columns.

This is my structure:

> CREATE TABLE logs (
>   log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
>   log_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   error_text TEXT
>   )

but when I am inserting into the table the `log_date` field remain blank:
`INSERT INTO logs(error_text)VALUES("some error text")`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ba5be/1

Comment: Are you sure the `log_date` field remains blank? Maybe you're not selecting it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `null` as placeholder in your insert query

This works

```
INSERT INTO logs(error_text)
VALUES("some error text");
```

This not

```
INSERT INTO logs(error_text, log_date)
VALUES("some error text", null);
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f25b5/1)

Comment: Isn't that what he's doing?

Comment: Obviously not. If he did then the code he provided would work.

Comment: Maybe the problem lies somewhere else? Old version of SQLite or something, but I dont know, let's wait for OP to reply.

Comment: @juergend Thanks for your response but this is exactly what I am doing...
do you have any other solutions?

Comment: @Octoshape how do I check my sqLite version?

Comment: @user2979757 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646353/how-to-find-sqlite-database-file-version

Answer (score 0):

I just had potentially the same issue, and found your question while looking for a solution.

In my case the issue is that SQLite Administrator is showing '0' in all the log_date columns.  However writing a "SELECT * from logs" in my C# application shows that the data is correct, even from previous sessions, before I'd noticed the issue (Changed names to match your schema).

So I'm putting this down to a bug in SQLite Administrator, although did not find confirmation with a quick Google search.