# What sqlite version we use and what is my database file version?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Problem 1:
When we creat a sqlite database with sqlite IDE or coding we don’t define sqlite version(1/2/3).  So what is the default version and which version we use automatically?

Problem 2:
Is there any way to get my current  and old sqlite database file version by java coding or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android

Comment: It's almost certain that you're on some 3.x version (seeing as it came out ten years ago). Also relevant: [How to find SQLITE database file version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646353/how-to-find-sqlite-database-file-version)

Comment: first problem is clear to me. But I don't konw how to use magic header and this type of command.

$ file file2.db
file2.db: SQLite 2.x database

$ file file3.db
file3.db: SQLite 3.x database @rutter

Comment: [`file`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) is a Unix command.  As far as the header, you can check the first 16 bytes of the file: if they are equal to the string `SQLite format 3`, you are apparently dealing with a SQLite 3.x database file. [SQLite's documentation describes their file header in some detail](http://sqlite.org/fileformat.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it. Can you help me about second question. @rutter

Comment: By database version, do you really mean the sqlite engine version i.e.  3 really for android-sqlite, or the schema version you use e.g. when calling `SQLiteOpenHelper` super constructor?

Comment: Now I want to know schema version. @laalto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Android sqlite is sqlite3. The specific version [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android) on the device and software version.
2. You can get your schema version with [`SQLiteDatabase` `getVersion()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion%28%29) in Java code or [`PRAGMA user_version`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) in SQL.