# How can I tell whether my database is SQLite 2 or 3?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I migrated our MySQL database to SQLite using a MySQL to SQLite shell script that I found online somewhere. There was no mention on what version of SQLite database it creates.

How can I check, on Windows what version it is?

I checked online on how to do it, but most used `file` command etc. that is for Linux.

And, if it created an old version how do I upgrade it on Windows?

On MySQL we would just install a newer version, but since it's just a file, how to do it?

Comment: where did you find the shell script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646353/how-to-find-sqlite-database-file-version

Answer (score 1):

Run a select statement:
" SELECT sqlite_version() AS 'SQLite Version'; "

To update your mysql server, download the latest version on: 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
And dont forget to make a backup first ;)