# sqlite database file unreadable symbols

Tags: python, database, sqlite

We have an assignment where we have to write and query from a database file directly without the use of any sqlite api functions. We were given the site https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html as guidance but I can't seem to get the database file to look like anything readable.

Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do with the sqlite3 library from python

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("PRAGMA page_size = 4096")
cur.execute("PRAGMA encoding = 'UTF-8'")
dropTable = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employee"
createTable = "CREATE TABLE Employee(first int, second int, third int)"

cur.execute(dropTable)
cur.execute(createTable)

cur.execute("INSERT INTO Employee VALUES (1, 2, 3)")

con.commit()
con.close()
```

When I open the database file, it starts with "SQLite format 3", and then a bunch of weird symbols following it. The same thing happened when I made the databse with the actual csv file given. There's some readable parts but most of it is unreadable symbols that is in no way similar to the format specified by the website. I'm a little overwhelmed right now so I would appreciate anyone pointing me to the right direction on how I would begin fixing this mess.

Comment: How are you examining the file? With a hex editor?

Comment: And what's not matching up with the description of the file format?

Comment: After the "SQLite format 3" are a series of bytes as described in the format. You will probably need to use [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) to interpret them (if you actually need their values).

Comment: With glogg. I don't think the editor is the issue though, I can open the example file without any issue. The demo file they gave us had the first few lines like this  00000000: 5351 4c69 7465 2066 6f72  SQLite for
0000000a: 6d61 7420 3300 1000 0101  mat 3.....

Comment: You mean the log explorer [glogg](https://glogg.bonnefon.org/)? It seems not suitable for opening of binary files.

Comment: The first 16 bytes should be (in base 16)  `53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00` so that looks right...

Comment: So the demo file given was a binary file, I changed the line "con = sqlite3.connect('test.bin')", is there a specific way I was supposed to convert the output to binary format?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do this without the sqlite3 api?

Comment: You can call the database file whatever you want; that's not going to change the file format... Were you expecting a human readable text file?

Comment: Yeah, we can't use any built in queries. The exercise is for us to go through the b+ tree format manually and see if the scan times matches the ones proposed.

Comment: Then I think you are stuck with opening the file in binary mode and using python `struct`.

Comment: Alright, I'm an idiot and I just figured it out that it was indeed an editor issue. I downloaded a binary file viewer and everything looked exactly like the demo. So can Python read the lines like a normal file or do I have to do any conversions first? The instructions in the assignment says to read directly from the file, so I'm guessing Python can actually read those snowflake symbols and then I use struct to make them human readable right?

Comment: Yes, and you must be sure to open the file in [binary](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html?highlight=fileio#binary-i-o) mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of reading that binary file using `FileIO` and `struct`:

```
from io import FileIO
from struct import *


def read_header(db):
    # read the entire database header into one bytearray
    header = bytearray(100)
    db.readinto(header)

    # print out a few of the values in the header
    # any number that is more than one byte requires unpacking
    # strings require decoding
    print('header string: ' + header[0:15].decode('utf-8')) # note that this ignores the null byte at header[15]
    page_size = unpack('>h', header[16:18])[0]
    print('page_size = ' + str(page_size))
    print('write version: ' + str(header[18]))
    print('read version: ' + str(header[19]))
    print('reserved space: ' + str(header[20]))
    print('Maximum embedded payload fraction: ' + str(header[21]))
    print('Minimum embedded payload fraction: ' + str(header[22]))
    print('Leaf payload fraction: ' + str(header[23]))
    file_change_counter = unpack('>i', header[24:28])[0]
    print('File change counter: ' + str(file_change_counter))
    sqlite_version_number = unpack('>i', header[96:])[0]
    print('SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER: ' + str(sqlite_version_number))


db = FileIO('test.db', mode='r')
read_header(db)
```

This only reads the database header, and ignores most of the values in the header.

Comment: When you get a bit further, this [varint implementation](https://github.com/fmoo/python-varint) may be useful.